# Matlab: Long, multiline, Legends with latex interpreters

Tags: matlab-figure, legend

I have several lines in a figure, each of them having their own legend entries. One of the legend entries is quite long, and I need it to split up into lines. Further, since I have some symbols coming up, I need to use the latex interpreter.

Everything is fine except I can't seem to split up the long legend entry. Standard latex commands like '\\', or '\par', or '\newline' doesn't seem to be working and only leaves a single space in the output.

Would be grateful if someone can help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sprintf` to embed '`\n`' inside `legend()`

```
legend(sprintf('%s\n%s', 'line', 'line'))
```

and `legend('line\nline')` won't work.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid now. I had known about this, except I thought it didn't work on latex interpreter. Now that you've told, I gave it a try and it worked. Thanks a lot for the answer! Cheers!